# MS access: Can not select any option in dropdown

Tags: ms-access

In my ms access project I have lots of dropdown list. Suddenly I found a problem with most of the dropdownlist. The dropdown list show properly but I can not select any option from that list. For some of the list I can select options but most of the dropdownlist is not select-able. In the picture below, I have shown one of my dropdownlist. As you can see, I am trying to select Descending but it is not being selected. How can I solve this problem and why this is happenning all of a sudden in my whole project?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **bound** combobox behaves like this if the record is not updateable. It knows you can't write to the record, so you can't select anything.

If your whole project is affected, maybe your database (or the backend) has become read-only? Or you have lost write privileges on the network share?

**Unbound** comboboxes would still work as usually. They don't have a database field associated to write into.

This could be a possible explanation for some dropdowns still working.

Comment: You cannot use either type of comboboxes if the control or form is not editable.

Comment: well, I made all forms uneditable few days ago and that was causing the problem. Thanks

Comment: Andre your answer is not correct, the correct answer is my comment, which you have not included.

Comment: @Fionnuala: Sorry, but you are wrong. If you e.g. set the RecordsetType property of a form to **Snapshot**, and have bound and unbound comboboxes on the form. Then they behave exactly as described: the bound combobox can be "dropped down", but nothing can be selected. With the unbound combobox, you can select a value. --- Please try it out (and reconsider your downvote...)

Comment: "well, I made all forms uneditable few days ago and that was causing the problem. Thanks –  user1670773" -- please review your answer.

Comment: @Fionnuala: "A bound combobox behaves like this if the record is not updateable." This describes exactly what happened. I really don't understand what you're getting at. --- "For some of the list I can select options" How else than with an unbound combobox could this happen?